# Android: default music player widget on lockscreen

Tags: android, widget, lockscreen

I have my own music player and I want to interact with the DEFAULT player widget on the lock screen. So my question is how can I make this widget display on lock screen like what google player is doing and what broadcasting message should be used to remove it from the lock screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have my own music player and I want to interact with the DEFAULT player widget on the lock screen.

On Android 4.0 and 4.1, if your app is a media player, you can register a `RemoteControlClient` to interact with music controls that appear on the lockscreen.

On Android 4.2, you would need to write your own lockscreen app widget AFAIK.

Comment: Great, thanks!! But can I also use RemoteControlClient to remove the widget from the lockscreen as well?

Comment: never mind, I figured that out! Thank you very much!!